# Sketch the graph for $0^\circ \leqslant x \leqslant 360^\circ$.

Tags: trigonometry

Sketch the graph $y= cos \frac{3}{4}x-2$ for $0^\circ \leqslant x \leqslant 360^\circ$.

Please help me draw this.

I found out that $y= cos \frac{3}{4}x-2$ has a period of $\frac{360^\circ}{\frac{3}{4}}$ = $480^\circ$

How to draw this....it must have one cycle only...I guess....

Comment: Draw a table, input and ouput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For questions like these, try Wolfram Alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos%283x/4%29-2%20from%200%20to%20360%20degrees).

[image: plot cos(3x/4)-2 from 0 to 360 degrees]

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot attach a graph to a comment (am I right?). Here the result with fooplot...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use https://functionplotter.com/ for your online graph-sketching needs.

I advise that you play around with the functions: if you have $y = A(\sin(B(x-C))+D$, changing each of the $A,B,C,D$ components will influence your graph. Try to learn what they do. If still unclear, refer to [this](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATT7/sinusoidal.htm) helpful site.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: the graph comes like a straight line! but a sin graph must not be a straight line. anyways thanks

Comment: Actually is working very well... May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: @Kiara all you have to do is enter "cos(3x/4)-2".